# Easiest way to corrupt ext3 file system (for testing)?

Tags: ext3

I need to corrupt ext3 file system (for testing purposes) to some repairable state. How that can be done?

Comment: How repairable do you want it?  All data recoverable, or just back to a functional filesystem?

Comment: Also see the other answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140253/how-can-i-simulate-ext3-filesystem-corruption .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'mkswap /dev/ext3_dev' or 'dd if=/dev/zerro of=/dev/ext3_dev bs=1024 skip=1000 count=300'

Comment: if=/dev/null won't do as much as /dev/zero

Comment: of course /dev/zerro

Answer (score 0):

Well, create ext3 on lvm and shrink lvm, mkfs.ext3 without umounting, some lowlevel tool to delete inodes...

Answer (score 0):

I'd write simple C-program for that doing a number of random seeks & destroy.

Answer (score 0):

How about just 'fsck' the filesystem while it is mounted, and you are writing some thing to it. This should work pretty consistently.